# Maui Popup action: How to style to dark/light mode changes?

Tags: maui

I have a Maui app that responds to the user preference and changes to dark mode or [Theme Switching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/system-theme-changes). I haven't been able to figure out how to have the [Popups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/pop-ups) respond or change styling fully. The button/action color is Primary (I think) I would prefer to not change that.

[image]

Comment: UPDATE: the simple Prompt is not the only Popup we are using. ActionSheet +++

Answer (score 0):

I customized the Popup style in dark mode and normal mode by using MAUI Community Toolkit's Popup.

Specifically, you can [bind the app theme](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/system-theme-changes) in custom popup file like the below code:

```
<toolkit:Popup xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
               xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
               xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
               x:Class="MyProject.SimplePopup">
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Label Text="This is a very important message!" />
        <Button Text="OK" 
                TextColor="{AppThemeBinding Light=Green, Dark=Red}"
                Clicked="OnOKButtonClicked" />
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</toolkit:Popup>
```

For details, you can refer to the [Popup - .NET MAUI Community Toolkit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/views/popup)

Comment: Thanks, I understand that I can go fully custom and will as a last resort. BUT this seems like a bug if the Maui Framework doesn't deal with this without going fully custom.

Comment: @kenny In android, you can change the color variables in YOURPROJECT\Platforms\Android\Resources\values\colors.xml, and Specifically, you can refer to [Changing the DisplayAlert button color](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/discussions/6579)

Comment: Thanks for that susggestion as I hinted at in the question. I'll dig in and see if the specific Popup action text can be separate from the Primay color.

Comment: @kenny May I know whether your issue has been solved or not? If not, can you share it in here? We can work together to figure it out.

Comment: Thanks for the work arounds. No, IMO it's a bug. I will probably work around it by changing to a color that works for both dark and light mode and switches or going fullly custom on all the popups we use. It seems to be the Maui Framework popups should support dark/light theme changes somehow. Perhaps they do, but I haven't found it yet.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/pop-ups